# Getting an "InvalidCastException was unhandled error" when filling up a parameter

Tags: c#

I am doing a program that calculates quiz and exam scores and it should show the equivalent grade and letter(i.e. 95=A) using windows form.

I've created a struct and it contains the student number, student name, scores of 4 quizzes and 1 exam. On this struct, I also created encapsulations, a method, and a constructor.

This struct is on a different file/class. I've created a button that will run the method for computing the scores. Here's my problem, the constructor I've created for this struct is having an error whenever I press my "compute" button.

```
StudentInfo compute = new StudentInfo(Convert.ToInt32(tb_studentID),
Convert.ToString(tb_studentName),
Convert.ToDouble(tb_quiz1), Convert.ToDouble(tb_quiz2),
Convert.ToDouble(tb_tp1), Convert.ToDouble(tb_tp2),
Convert.ToDouble(tb_exam));
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Resolve what error?

Comment: I bet tb_studentID and so on are textboxes and you don't write the property Text which is taking the value from the TextBox. So write tb_studentID.Text, also it will be good to be use double.TryParse.

Comment: @TimSchmelter C#2010 says "InvalidCastException was unhandled". The computation won't go through. I can't get any result when I enter the scores.

Comment: What does the exception stack trace tell you? What are the types of those `tb_*` variables/fields? What values did they contain when this exception was thrown?

Comment: Refer this [InvalidCastException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.invalidcastexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @mybirthname I tried your suggestion, the error changed. It's now "FormatException was unhandled"

Comment: Now you need to use double.TryParse to check if the text is valid double

Comment: @PieterWitvoet i am very new to programming i dont know what the exception stack trace is. The studentID is an int, the studentName is a string, the quiz1, quiz2, tp1, tp2, and exam are all doubles. i input 95 to all of the textboxes and it gave me the error message.

Comment: @mybirthname so I just replace those `Convert.ToDouble` to `double.TryParse`, right?

Comment: @Marion Did my solution solves your problem, or is there some problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

Use `TryParse` instead of `Convert` methods. This will prevent you from having "InvalidCastExceptions". Furthermore you need to use the `Text` property of `TextBox`, not the `TextBox` itself. Try it just like this:

```
int studentId;
double quiz2;

if (int.TryParse(tb_studentID.Text, out studentId) && double.TryParse(tb_quiz2.Text, out quiz2) && 
...) {
     StudentInfo compute = new StudentInfo(studentId, quiz2 ...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You are not using C# 2010 but Visual Studio 2010
2. The problem is not in the constructor but in the conversions
3. You can't cast any of the variables to the type you are trying to cast it. Try to convert all the parameters 1 by 1 and see where the problem is.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the reply. I will now do it 1 by 1. I'll be back in a few minutes.